# How to use variational calculus on a ratio of two functionals, with inequality constraint associated with the denominator?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, variational-analysis

I wish to optimize $J=\frac{I_1}{I_2}$ where $I_2=\int_0^T f(t)\theta(f(t))dt$. Where $\theta(.)$ is the Heaviside step function. To avoid using the step function (since it is not differentiable) , I wrote an inequality constraint $f(t)\geq0$ only for the bottom functional and hence got: $I_2=\int_0^T f(t)dt$. Furthermore, $I_1=\int_0^T f(t)dt$ without the constraint. This entire functional J is subjected to an equality constraint $h(t)=0$. Any help, including being pointed to a good resource, is extremely appreciated.

Edit: Fixed the wording, and defined $\theta(.)$ after seeing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing a ratio of two functionals, especially with constraints, is a problem often approached using the calculus of variations alongside methods from the field of constrained optimization such as Lagrange multipliers.

Given the functionals:

\begin{equation}
I_2 = \int_{0}^{T} f(t)\theta(f(t))\,dt
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
I_1 = \int_{0}^{T} f(t)\,dt
\end{equation}

and the constraint \begin{equation}( h(t) = 0 )\end{equation}, if we wish to optimize the functional:

\begin{equation}
J = \frac{I_1}{I_2}
\end{equation}

subject to \begin{equation}( f(t) \geq 0 )\end{equation}, we can reformulate the problem using a Lagrange multiplier \begin{equation}( \lambda(t) )\end{equation} to enforce the inequality constraint and a multiplier \begin{equation}( \mu )\end{equation} for the equality constraint.

We define a Lagrangian \begin{equation}( \mathcal{L} )\end{equation} as:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(f(t), \lambda(t), \mu) = I_1 - \mu I_2 - \int_{0}^{T} \lambda(t) f(t) \,dt
\end{equation}

where \begin{equation}( \lambda(t) \geq 0 )\end{equation} is the Lagrange multiplier corresponding to the inequality constraint. The term \begin{equation}( -\int_{0}^{T} \lambda(t) f(t) \,dt )\end{equation} is included to ensure that \begin{equation}( f(t) \geq 0 )\end{equation}, as \begin{equation}( \lambda(t) f(t) = 0 )\end{equation} when the constraint is active.

The condition for optimality is that the functional derivative of \begin{equation}( \mathcal{L} )\end{equation} with respect to \begin{equation}( f(t) )\end{equation} should vanish, i.e., \begin{equation}( \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta f(t)} = 0 )\end{equation}, which gives us:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta I_1}{\delta f(t)} - \mu \frac{\delta I_2}{\delta f(t)} - \lambda(t) = 0
\end{equation}

Moreover, we must satisfy the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions due to the inequality constraint:

\begin{equation}
\lambda(t) \geq 0, \quad f(t) \geq 0, \quad \lambda(t) f(t) = 0
\end{equation}

To solve this optimization problem, one must typically assume specific forms for \begin{equation}( f(t) )\end{equation} and \begin{equation}( \theta(f(t)) )\end{equation}, or at least their variational derivatives, to proceed with finding explicit solutions or numerical approximations.

It should be noted that the problem of optimizing a ratio is not standard in the calculus of variations and might not admit a closed-form solution. In practice, one might need to employ numerical methods to find ( f(t) ) that optimizes \begin{equation}( J )\end{equation}, while satisfying the given constraints.

This is a broad outline of the approach to solving the given problem. The specifics would depend on the form of \begin{equation}( f(t) )\end{equation}, \begin{equation}( \theta(f(t)) )\end{equation}, and \begin{equation}( h(t) )\end{equation}, which were not provided in the question. Therefore, the exact solution procedure could vary significantly. For a comprehensive treatment of such problems, one might consult resources on constrained optimization and the calculus of variations.

###############  EDIT ########################

Optimizing a functional that is a ratio of two integrals, particularly when one of the integrals involves the Heaviside step function, requires careful handling of non-differentiability. We are given:

\begin{equation}
I_1 = \int_{0}^{T} f(t)\, dt
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
I_2 = \int_{0}^{T} f(t) \theta(f(t))\, dt
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation}
\theta(f(t))
\end{equation}
is the Heaviside step function, which equals 1 if
\begin{equation}
f(t) \geq 0
\end{equation}
and 0 otherwise. This step function ensures that
\begin{equation}
I_2
\end{equation}
only accumulates positive values of
\begin{equation}
f(t)
\end{equation}
. We wish to optimize the functional:

\begin{equation}
J = \frac{I_1}{I_2}
\end{equation}

subject to the constraint
\begin{equation}
f(t) \geq 0
\end{equation}
. To handle the non-differentiability of
\begin{equation}
\theta(f(t))
\end{equation}
and to include the inequality constraint, we can introduce a Lagrange multiplier
\begin{equation}
\lambda(t)
\end{equation}
for the constraint. The resulting Lagrangian
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}
\end{equation}
would be:

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}(f(t), \lambda(t)) = I_1 - \int_{0}^{T} \lambda(t) (f(t) - 0) \, dt
\end{equation}

where
\begin{equation}
\lambda(t) \geq 0
\end{equation}
is the Lagrange multiplier associated with the inequality constraint
\begin{equation}
f(t) \geq 0
\end{equation}
.

For
\begin{equation}
I_2
\end{equation}
, since the Heaviside function is not differentiable, we cannot directly use the standard method of Lagrange multipliers which requires differentiability. Instead, we would need to use a method capable of handling non-smooth optimization problems.

One approach is to utilize the concept of subdifferentials in convex analysis. The subdifferential of
\begin{equation}
\theta(f(t))
\end{equation}
, denoted by
\begin{equation}
\partial \theta(f(t))
\end{equation}
, contains all subgradients at
\begin{equation}
f(t)
\end{equation}
, which are the allowable slopes that can serve as "derivatives" for optimization purposes.

The condition for
\begin{equation}
f(t)
\end{equation}
to be optimal is that the subgradient of
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}
\end{equation}
with respect to
\begin{equation}
f(t)
\end{equation}
must include 0, which can be formulated as:

\begin{equation}
0 \in \frac{\delta I_1}{\delta f(t)} - \lambda(t) + \partial \theta(f(t))
\end{equation}

Additionally, the complementary slackness condition from the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions must be satisfied:

\begin{equation}
\lambda(t) f(t) = 0
\end{equation}

Because
\begin{equation}
\theta(f(t))
\end{equation}
is discontinuous, the analysis becomes significantly more complex and requires specialized techniques.

The overall problem of optimizing
\begin{equation}
J
\end{equation}
with the constraint
\begin{equation}
f(t) \geq 0
\end{equation}
does not yield to standard variational calculus methods due to the presence of the non-differentiable Heaviside function. Instead, one must employ methods from non-smooth optimization, which might lead to a numerical rather than analytical solution.

For further resources on such optimization problems, one can refer to texts on convex analysis and non-smooth optimization, such as "Convex Analysis" by R. Tyrrell Rockafellar or "Nonsmooth Analysis and Control Theory" by F.H. Clarke.

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't clear in my question. $\theta(.)$ is the Heaviside step function,ensuring that in the I2 functional, I accumulate only the positive values of f(t). The whole reason I introduced the inequality constraint is to avoid writing the step function, as it isn't differentiable. And this inequality constraint is only on the bottom functional, NOT the top one, since only the bottom one has the step function in it.